# Rowdeleteing event in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have been trying to write this simple logic of deleting a row from the gridview and from the SQL database of the selected row, but keep getting a null reference to cell, which has the primary key [ID] in a field.

Here's my html:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="grvInventoryEdit" runat="server" BackColor="White" onrowdeleting="grvInventoryEdit_RowDeleting" 
                onrowediting="grvInventoryEdit_RowEditing" 
                onrowupdating="grvInventoryEdit_RowUpdating">
<Columns>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                    <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" /><asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id">
                       <ItemTemplate>
                           <%#Eval("No")%>
                       </ItemTemplate>
                       <EditItemTemplate>
                           <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEditNo" ReadOnly="True" Text='<%#Eval("No")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                       </EditItemTemplate>
                   </asp:TemplateField>........ </Columns> </asp:GridView>
```

And my back-end code for rowdeleting event is :

```
protected void grvInventoryEdit_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
      TextBox id = (TextBox)grvInventoryEdit.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEditNo");

      Asset asset = db.Assets.Single(a => a.No == Convert.ToInt32(id));            

        db.Assets.DeleteOnSubmit(asset);
        db.SubmitChanges();

        binddata();
    }
```

and when the event fires, this is what i am seeing while debugging:[image: Picture Below]

I am not sure why i am getting a null value ,though, there is a value for that cell.

Could you tell me what i am doing wrong ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, in my HTML, i have only the value that's bound to the item, is being displayed, and there are no textboxes in my `<ItemTemplate>`, hence, it pulls null value.  Whereas, in my `<EditItemTemplate>` there is a textbox, which can pull the value from the cell.

So I changed my HTML to this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id">
   <ItemTemplate>`<asp:label runat="server" ID="lblEditNo"  ReadOnly="True" Text='<%#Eval("No")%>'></asp:label>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <EditItemTemplate>
     <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEditNo" ReadOnly="True" Text='<%#Eval("No")%>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

and no change in my codebehind, and this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `TextBox` object instead instead of `Text` property of `TextBox`

```
Asset asset = db.Assets.Single(x=>x.No == Convert.ToInt32(id.Text));
```

and your `TextBox` is also coming null means it's unable to find it in GridView, try like this:

```
TextBox id = e.Row.FindControl("txtEditNo");
```

Also see [this CodeProject article to understand how to use ItemTemplate and EditItemTemplate](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37207/Editable-Gridview-with-Textbox-CheckBox-Radio-Butt)

Comment: @Eshan, thanks, but there is no Row property for e in the RowUpdating event.  Thanks for the article, will go through it.

Comment: You are right @Ehsan, i shoud set the id.Text to grab, but in my previous step, i am getting a null value for id, and the next step [Asset asset = ...] throws "Object reference not set ...." exception..

Comment: Yes from Grid your code is not getting TextBox from row

Comment: so, how do i get the value ?  the method i used to grab the value is still showing null..in the URL you provided, i couldnt find anything for rowdeleting event...

Comment: Read that article will help

Answer (score 1):

Might be it is due to the readonly property of textbox, not suer.

If you want to use the image button for edit and delete then use

```
protected void ibtnDelete_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)((ImageButton)sender).NamingContainer;
    Int32 UserId = Convert.ToInt32(gvUsers.DataKeys[gvRow.RowIndex].Value);
    // delete and hide the row from grid view
    if (DeleteUserByID(UserId))
        gvRow.Visible = false;
}
```

[For complete code see](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1101/insert-update-and-delete-in-asp-net-gridview-step-by-step)

Comment: removing the readonly property didnt help. However, i tried to get the ID using datakey like : Int32 UserId =    Convert.ToInt32(grvInventoryEdit.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);  and it throws "Index out of range..." exception.

Answer (score 1):

1. why are you adding a second commandfield instead of just enabling the delete button on the existing one.
2. if you are using a command field you should be supplying an compatible datasource that provides Delete functionality
3. if you're *"rolling your own"* delete functionality then just use a regular Button control and supply a CommandName and CommandArgument, such as **`CommandName="MyDelete" CommandArgument=<row number>`** where **`<row number>`** is supplied via GridView RowDataBound() event.
4. Regardless of how you choose to implement `Delete` you should be placing the key field in the GridView **`DataKeys`** Property and not as a field within each row.  This will make obtaining the PK far easier than what you are trying to do

Comment: thanks @fnostro, i have solved it by rearranging my ItemTemplate items.